# Can a simple undirected graph have multiple different cycle decompositions?

Tags: graph-theory

A cycle decomposition of a graph corresponds to an edge coloring† such that, for each color, the edges of that color form a cycle. My question is: Can a simple undirected graph have multiple different cycle decompositions?

†This is not necessarily a *proper* edge coloring (in which no two edges that share a vertex have the same color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, incredibly easily.

A graph has a cycle decomposition if and only if every degree is even, and in that case, we can find a cycle decomposition greedily. Pick a cycle (any cycle!), color it, and remove it from the graph. The remaining graph will still have the property that every degree is even, so we can keep going. When we have no more cycles to pick, it can only be because we have no more edges.

If you've found one cycle decomposition, then to find a *different* one, you just have to begin the process again, but start with a cycle that wasn't part of your first cycle decomposition! As long as that's possible, there will be multiple cycle decompositions.

I think the smallest graph for which this will work is the graph below:

```
 a----b----c
  \   |\  /
   \  | \/
    \ | /\
     \|/  \
      d----e
```

It has three cycle decompositions, each consisting of a $3$-cycle - which is $(a,b,d,a)$, $(b,c,d,b)$, or $(b,d,e,b)$ - and a $4$-cycle made up of whatever's left.

Comment: Perfect! For an additional visual representation, I've used Graphviz to illustrate the three cycle decompositions of the example graph. It can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzFrJ.png).